# why is $ with variable name not required in condition section and increment section c style for loop syntax in bash?

Tags: bash

`for (( i=1; i <= 5; i++ ))`  $ not required with i in expression `i<=5` and `i++` why so ? But when using i inside the body of for loop we are required to write $  as in the following example :

`if(( $i%2==0 ))
  then 
  b[$i]=$((-1*b[$i]))`

OR

`echo "Random number $i: $RANDOM"`

both above code snippet use $i.

Comment: `b[i]` is valid if `b` is a numerically-indexed (vs associative) array. In an associative array, `i` is a valid key name as a string, so an automatic numeric evaluation wouldn't be safe.

Comment: ...for that matter, you have three different contexts here: `$(( ))` is POSIX-specified and standardized, whereas `(( ))` on its own is a ksh extensions (that behaves identically to that standardized syntax)... whereas arrays aren't POSIX-specified at all.

Comment: The `for`-loop syntax you're asking about is described in detail at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for, and there's a good page on arithmetic expansion in bash in general at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr. Beyond that, though, I don't know exactly what your question is asking, and thus how to answer it. "Why did the language designers choose to do X?" isn't really a cloudsourceable question -- it's David Korn who made the decisions at hand (albeit later adopted in part by the Austin Group), so if you wanted a canonical answer, you'd need to go to him.

Comment: ("Why is syntax X useful?" is more answerable, but also rather broad-of-scope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(( ))` creates an arithmetic context. Quoting from [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name
>   without using the parameter expansion syntax.

`bash` tries to expand the name until it finds a valid value (you will get an error if you reach limit):

```
var=foo
foo=bar
bar=3
echo "$((var))"    #prints "3"
```

Example of other constructs that create an arithmetic context:

```
#regular arrays, doesn't work like that for associative arrays
declare -a arr=(a b c d)
num=2
echo "${arr[num]}"    #prints "c"

#substring expansion
var=foobar
echo "${var:num}"     #prints "obar"

#etc
```

Even `[[ ]]` with some operators creates an arithmetic context (note that `[ ]` behaves differently):

```
var=10
[[ $var -eq 10 ]] && echo yes    #prints "yes"
[[ var -eq 10 ]] && echo yes     #prints "yes"
[[ var -eq 11 ]] && echo yes     #prints nothing
[[ var = 10 ]] && echo yes       #prints nothing
[[ $var = 10 ]] && echo yes      #prints "yes"
```

---

Is there any reason to use `$` then?

For example, thanks to `$`, you can use parameter expansion, such as substring expansion:

```
var=foo123
echo "$((${var:3} + 5))"    #prints "128"
```

Another example could be specifying a base:

```
foo=09
echo "$((foo))"        #error
echo "$((10#foo))"     #error
echo "$((10#$foo))"    #ok - prints "9"
```

As I have mentioned, associative arrays (declared with `declare -A`) **do not** create an arithmetic context (because the index doesn't have to be a number):

```
declare -A arr2=([10]=a [11]=b [12]=c)
index=11
echo "${arr2[index]}"     #prints nothing
echo "${arr2[$index]}"    #prints "b"
```

---

Your examples:

```
#arithmetic context - no need for $
for (( i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ))

#arithmetic context - no need for $
if (( i % 2 == 0 ))

#if it's a regular array: arithmetic context - no need for $
b[i]=$(( -1 * b[i] ))

#NO arithmetic context - $ needed
echo "Random number $i: $RANDOM"
```

Answer (score 0):

The construct (( ... )), mostly used for arithmetic expressions do not require the $ to reference variables, I don't know why (maybe to let the expressions have a C-style look).

In you example code, you can use `if (( i%2==0 ))`, without $, because of the double parentheses.

Comment: Not just "mostly" -- it **is** "arithmetic context", as in, that's what it's called in the documentation. `=` becomes an assignment; `<` a numeric less-than, etc.

Comment: Also, note that `$(( ))` is POSIX-standardized, but `(( ))` is not -- so for `/bin/sh`, we'd need something more like `if [ "$(( i % 2 ))" -eq 0 ]`.

Answer (score 0):

It always work to add a dollar sign to a variable name when referencing the variable.

In some cases, the dollar sign can be omitted.

A frequently encountered case is to reference a variable within a test which involves integer comparisons using opertors -eq, -ne, -lt, -le -gt, -ge (these operators assume the involving variables are integers). For example:
`[[ a -gt 3 ]]`

I would say that this is really a bad syntax sugar which reduces the uniformity of bash syntax. The usefulness of this syntax sugar is low and the harmfulness of introducing bugs is high.