# Why can substring variable expansion reference a variable without a dollar sign?

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

In bash, to get the first 4 characters of a variable, you can do:

```
variable='this is a variable'
echo ${variable:0:4}
```

Instead of hard-coding the length, you can reference a variable like this:

```
length=4
echo ${variable:0:$length}
```

However, it seems that you can leave off the `$` off `length` as well:

```
echo ${variable:0:length}
```

It does not make sense to me that you should be able to do this because I always thought that to use/evaluate a variable, you have to prefix it with `$`.

In other languages, I would expect the text after each `:` to be a number or an expression that evaluates to a number. And in bash, `length` wouldn't evaluate to anything, but `$length` would.

This is confusing. Could someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: Same thing with this trick: the sigil '$' is not needed in this case too : `x=( a b c ); echo ${x[RANDOM % 3]}`

Comment: The shell auto-expands variables in its arithmetic contexts, and string indexes are arithmetic contexts. Related questions: ["why is $ with variable name not required in condition section and increment section c style for loop syntax in bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210875/why-is-with-variable-name-not-required-in-condition-section-and-increment-sect/48212768) and ["Where does the recursive variable expansion in bash/shell numeric contexts come from?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980940/where-does-the-recursive-variable-expansion-in-bash-shell-numeric-contexts-come)

Comment: @sergio That's describing indirect expansion, invoked by `!` (as in `${!varname}`), which is quite a bit different from auto-expansion in arithmetic contexts.

Comment: @Gordon, that's the answer - I think it shouldn't be a comment.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks! Is there a full list somewhere of places that are considered an arithmetic context? Are arithmetic contexts the only places that the shell auto-expands variables or are there others?

Answer (score 1):

In general is correct to use the "$" symbol to expand a variable, but in some cases the bash auto-expands variable. For example in context like arithmetics or indirect expansion
 (see [Shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) to more detailed information).
 However your case is a simple arithmetic context expansion.